# VB6 SendKeys problem

Tags: vb6, sendkeys

I am trying to create a button to enter "0" value into textbox.

```
Private Sub cmd0_Click()
    PvCurPaidAmt.SetFocus
    PvCurPaidAmt.SelStart = Len(PvCurPaidAmt) + 1
    PvCurPaidAmt.SelText = "0"
End Sub
```

Now the problem is the I have to change textbox to pvcurenccy texbox provided by third party api, that does not support SelStart and SelText functions, so I cannot use the code above.

I am trying to use SendKeys:

```
Private Sub cmd0_Click()
   PvCurPaidAmt.SetFocus
   SendKeys "0"
End Sub
```

Now the problem is it does not continue with the next cursor. I am trying to do what On-screen keyborard is doing. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by : it does not continue with the next cursor? Do you mean that the "0" is not typed? or is it typed but you are sent out of focus? Please add more details

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, when set focus to the PvCurPaidAmt control, you cannot be sure that the cursor will be at the end of the string (or that the whole string isn't selected or highlighted to begin with).

If the PvCurPaidAmt control has a .Text property, you could do:

```
PvCurPaidAmt.Text = PvCurPaidAmt.Text & "0"
```

If not, first SendKeys to send the cursor to the end:

```
SendKeys "{END}", True  ' it will force the app to wait till the keys are processed
```

then

```
SendKeys "0"
```